# How do VLANs Work? Some Basic Questions:

Tags: switch, router, vlan, ip-address

I've recently started looking into VLANs. I am a network novice so bear with me please:). I have a few questions regarding VLANs.

1. I understand that certain managed switches allow you to create VLANs. Say you create two vlans on a managed switch. Let's say the first one (10) is for your bedroom. In that bedroom you have 2 computers and a file server. The second one (20) is in your dining room which also has 2 computers and a file server. Theoretically a computer in the dining room can't access or even see the file server in the bedroom correct? If so, then lets say you want all the computers to have access to the internet. You would connect the switch to the LAN port on the router. But the router has it's own LAN so wouldn't the dining room now be able to access the bedroom file server as they are both technically on the routers LAN?
2. Assuming the info above is correct, how would you prevent this? Also, after preventing it, how could I, has the network admin gain access to both servers for maintenance?

Any info or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. Routers route traffic between networks (VLANs), so you need a router to route traffic between the VLANs.

Answer (score 2):

> Theoretically a computer in the dining room can't access or even see the file server in the bedroom correct?

Practically as well. Separating VLANs prevents direct (L2) communication between nodes.

> You would connect the switch to the LAN port on the router.

It largely depends on *how* you connect the switch to the router. Using a VLAN trunk, you would connect both VLANs at once (to separate router sub interfaces).

> But the router has it's own LAN

The router has several LAN interfaces that become part of the (V)LAN you connect them to.

Perhaps you're thinking of consumer-grade devices that often integrate a simple, unmanaged switch. Those things usually can't route between VLANs and are off-topic here.

> so  wouldn't the dining room now be able to access the bedroom file server as they are both technically on the routers LAN?

No. Routers usually have *routed* (or L3) interfaces that are part of different networks or VLANs. Only if you'd connect both VLANs to a *switch group* on the router, then you'd directly connect both VLANs, making them one. The point of VLANs is separating traffic, so reconnecting them on L2 doesn't make sense.

> Assuming the info above is correct, how would you prevent this?

Connecting the VLANs to different L3 interfaces enables routing between them. That routed traffic needs to cross the router, so you'd set up ACLs or firewall rules on the router to control the traffic.

> Also, after preventing it, how could I, has the network admin gain access to both servers for maintenance?

Simply permit required traffic in the ACLs or firewall rules.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think i'm starting to understand a bit better.I think maybe my overall impression of VLANs is incorrect. You said that connecting VLANS to different L3 interfaces enables routing between them. But isn't the point of a VLAN to make sure the devices on each vlan can't see eachother?

Comment: VLANs separate L2 segments / broadcast domains / IP subnets. Routers connect those (on L3) but they can control the traffic.